# Cómo convertir un dict en string en python

Tags: python, string, lambda

necesito convertir un diccionario en un string para listarlo en pantalla. El código que hice funciona, pero me parece absolutamente feo.
¿Cómo puedo mejorarlo? Sospecho que con alguna función lambda.. pero me trabé

```
def listar (jugador):
    j_pal = []
    j_pal2 =[]
    for p in range (len(jugador)):
        j_pal = j_pal + list(jugador[p].keys())
        j_pal2 = j_pal2 + list(jugador[p].values())
    pal_jug = ''
    for pal in range(len(jugador)):
       pal_jug = pal_jug + j_pal[pal].upper() + ': ' +j_pal2[pal] +' '
```

Comment: Puedes importar `pprint` y hacer `pprint.pprint(diccionario)`. Eso te lo sacará más organizado y con las claves en orden alfabético. Si no quieres que te modifique el orden de las claves, y usas Python 3.8 puedes pasarle el parámetro `sort_dicts=False`. Si no usas Python 3.8 no puedes evitar el cambio de orden con `pprint`. pero puedes usar entonces `json.dumps()` para convertir un diccionario en cadena, aunque el resultado no es exactamente python (por ejemplo si hay booleanos saldrán como `true` o `false` en vez de `True` o `False`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuve que agregar un `return pal_jug` que faltaba y agregar unos casos de prueba.

Este es el código a probar:

```
def listar (jugador):
    j_pal = []
    j_pal2 =[]
    for p in range (len(jugador)):
        j_pal = j_pal + list(jugador[p].keys())
        j_pal2 = j_pal2 + list(jugador[p].values())
    pal_jug = ''
    for pal in range(len(jugador)):
        pal_jug = pal_jug + j_pal[pal].upper() + ': ' +j_pal2[pal] +' '
    return pal_jug
```

**Programa de prueba 1**

```
word1 = dict(word1="Hola", word2="Mundo")
print(listar([word1]))
```

Produce

```
WORD1: Hola
```

**Programa de prueba 2**

```
word1 = dict(word1="Hello", word2="World", word3="Holland", word4="France")
word2 = dict(word1="Hola", word2="Mundo")
print(listar([word1, word2]))
```

produce

```
WORD1: Hello WORD2: World
```

**Programa de prueba 3**

```
dic1 = dict(uno=1, dos=2, tres=3)
print(listar([dic1]))
```

produce

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/candid/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch_10.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(listar([dic1]))
  File "/home/candid/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch_10.py", line 9, in listar
    pal_jug = pal_jug + j_pal[pal].upper() + ': ' +j_pal2[pal] +' '
TypeError: must be str, not int

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Análisis**

Cómo ejercicio está bien, pero como dijo @abulafia, hay alternativas mejores.

Volviendo al ejercicio en cuestión: El problema es que estás usando el número de entradas en el diccionario para armar la linea. Estas contando entradas en el diccionario, no las llaves que dejaste en `j_pal`. Por lo tanto, solo vas a imprimir una o dos llaves, segun pases uno o dos diccionarios.

El otro problema es que cuando armas `pal_jug` supones que el `j_pal2[pal]` es un string, entonces falla con enteros, flotantes, etc.

**Recomendaciónes**

Redefine la función para que reciba un diccionario, no una lista. Te simplificara la vida.

El valor puede ser cualquier cosa: un entero, flotante, una lista, otro diccionario ... tienes resolver como imprimir cada cual.

Revisa la línea

```
for pal in range(len(jugador)):
```

para que recorra todas las llaves del diccionario.

Escribe casos de pruebas. Haz un script y escribe todas las pruebas que se te ocurran. Ejecuta esas pruebas para revisar que todo funcione.

Comment: Gracias!!
En realidad el return no está porque las siguientes líneas son la actualización de una interfaz en PySimpleGUI